# How do Linux GPIO numbers get their values?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I am trying to understand how the Linux GPIO numbers get their values. 
e.g. [GPIO mapping for Joule](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000022494/boards-and-kits/intel-joule-kits.html).

I tried reading linux documentation on Pinctrl Subsystem and also looked at the code of GPIO driver being used in Intel Joule : 
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-broxton.c

However going this way looks very platform-specific. I am looking for some generic industry standard. Please help or please direct me to some good article.

Comment: There is no industry standard, it is up to the designers of each port to do something that makes sense for the GPIOs of the SoC they target, which is why you see different variations.  Questions which seek references to external articles are off-topic.

Comment: I can answer to your questions, but not today, a bit of weekend is here. In short, the global system numbers is not what you should care about at all. Only GPIO controller name (whatever it means on a certain system) and the relative to it PIN number makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, one has to get the difference between *Global System GPIO number* (GSGN) and relative to the certain GPIO controller. Earlier, before the era of GPIO descriptors, the GSGN had been used. After switching to the descriptor scheme the numbering scheme moves from (semi-)static GSGN to dynamic one and thus makes nonsense to the user. Instead the label of the pin, if any, or a pair of GPIO controller handle with a number **relative** to it became in use. This is being dictated by the resource providers, such as ACPI and Device Tree. If, by some reason, user wants to get the pair of the controller and relative number, the [libgpiod](https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/) library and tools gives the possibility to achieve this.

So, the link to Joule GPIO numbering scheme is really fragile, users are not suppose to know the GSGN. There are ways how to get the controller and relative number on a running system. But usually it's all related to the driver and ACPI tables and doesn't require any user involvement.

**Example:**

Take into consideration the pin `UART_1_TXD` (by some reason it's named in that document wrongly, should be `LPSS_UART1_TXD`). According to *[pinctrl-broxton.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-broxton.c)* this is pin 43 on a GPIO controller with ACPI _HID *INT34D1* and _UID *1*.

List all enumerated GPIO controllers (optional step):

```sh
# gpiodetect 
gpiochip0 [INT34D1:00] (83 lines)
gpiochip1 [INT34D1:01] (72 lines)
gpiochip2 [INT34D1:02] (42 lines)
gpiochip3 [INT34D1:03] (31 lines)
gpiochip4 [INT34D1:04] (20 lines)
```

Find one with _UID *1*:

```sh
# grep -w 1 /sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT34D1\:0*/uid
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT34D1:00/uid:1

# gpiodetect | grep -w INT34D1:00
gpiochip0 [INT34D1:00] (83 lines)
```

So, the interesting pair is: `gpiochip0 43`.

In the actual resource provider it will look like this (taken from [meta-acpi](https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi) project):

```asl
...
*   pin name           pin number   led
*   -----------------------------------------
*   ISH_GPIO_0_LS      35           heartbeat
*   ISH_GPIO_1_LS      33           sd-card
*   ISH_GPIO_2_LS      31           wifi
*   ISH_GPIO_3_LS      29           led-3
...
            GpioIo (
...
                "\\_SB.GPO2",               // GPIO controller
                0)                          // Must be 0
            {
                22,                         // ISH_GPIO_0_LS
                23,                         // ISH_GPIO_1_LS
                24,                         // ISH_GPIO_2_LS
                25                          // ISH_GPIO_3_LS
            }
...
```

Here you see the reference to the *Device* object thru a full path, i.e. *\_SB.GPO2*.

You may find more examples in [meta-acpi](https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi) project.

If by any weird case user really wants a non-sense number, this is the way:

```sh
# mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug/

# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/INT34D1\:00/gpio-ranges 
GPIO ranges handled:
0: INT34D1:00 GPIOS [429 - 460] PINS [0 - 31]
32: INT34D1:00 GPIOS [461 - 492] PINS [32 - 63]
64: INT34D1:00 GPIOS [493 - 511] PINS [64 - 82]

# echo $((43-32+461))
472
```

More details about GPIO library and subsystem can be found in [GPIO in-kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/index.html).

Comment: Awesome :) I was able to relate it very well. Infact, I cross-checked the concept on a different x86 platform and it all makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: One stupid question : The pinctrl-broxton driver : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-broxton.c defines so many GPIO pins. However, the document of Joule says that the board exposes 15 GPIOs (I assume its talking only about LS expansion header). Does all the pins defined in pinctrl-broxton driver physically exist ?

Comment: @InsaneCoder, they are physically exist, but not all of them are wired up to PCB.

Comment: One last question (which is the jist of this question) :  How did 429 became the base address for INT34D1:00 (`0: INT34D1:00 GPIOS [429 - 460] PINS [0 - 31]`)? What's the calculation happening in the background?

Comment: @InsaneCoder, by default (but it's not warranted!) the maximum GSGN on the x86 systems is 511 (the range 0-511), the allocation happens from the end towards beginning of the range.