# How to get GPIO interrupt from an IOexpander in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module, gpio

I am developing a kernel module for an embedded device, The device core is Toradex iMX6DL.

So I have an IO-Expander of mcp23xxx series on this device and I can work with its GPIOs. I can set them as input/output and get/set their values.

I need to use one of them as an interrupt, this is the part of my code for setting interrupt:

```c
static irqreturn_t r_irq_handler(unsigned int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
 {
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "interrupt received (irq: %d)\n", irq);
    //do some stuff here
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}


...

     if(gpio_request(497, 0)==0)
     {
         int result;             
         gpio_direction_input(497);
         gpio_set_debounce(497, 100);
         gpio_export(497,false);
         irqNumber =gpio_to_irq(497);        // map your GPIO to an IRQ
         printk("irq number : %d\r\n",irqNumber);
         result = request_irq(irqNumber,           // requested interrupt
                    (irq_handler_t) r_irq_handler, // pointer to handler function
                    IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, // interrupt mode flag
                    "irqHandler",        // used in /proc/interrupts
                    NULL);               // the *dev_id shared interrupt lines, NULL is okay

         printk("irq request for pin %d result:%d  \r\n",497,result);
         if(result == SUCCESS)
            printk("irq request for pin %d succeeds\r\n",497);
     }
```

The result of gpio_to_irq() is '-6' and the result of request_irq() is '-22', What should I do to get this GPIO's interrupt?

Comment: Where did you get that `497` from?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, you probably need to read a bit of documentation how numbers are allocated in Linux kernel for GPIO controllers. Also, this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55532410/2511795

Comment: @0andriy I surely need to, I don't know much about GPIO. I was just wondering if OP is using the correct value.

Comment: You need to add an error check to all calls you made. Also, what is that `gpio_export()` for?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli (I have unified comments to avoid pollution here): for me it's pretty much reasonable (512 - 16 + 1) as GPIO 0 out of 16 on this expander. UPDATE:  sorry, I miscalculated a bit, off-by-one error, you know, so, it seems GPIO 1.

Comment: The main issue here is that you are trying to use gpio_to_irq and gpios. What you should do is properly use device tree for your device and have the interrupts property of your node point to the mcp23xxx as an interrupt controller instead of a gpio controller. Then you can simply use platform_get_irq() to get the interrupt number.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the gpio number is correct, under the sys/class/gpio you can find the gpiochips and the starting number of those chips, mine is gpiochip496.

Comment: @0andriy I exported that pin just for a test, I wanted be able to get its value cause I did not get interrupt. So sorry for including that in my code it was just for a test of my circuit.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni Thank you, I will read about the platform_get_irq() and let you know the result.