# No response to GPIO with sysfs

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, gpio, sysfs

- Platform: Intel Apollo Lake N3350
- OS Platform: Ubuntu 18.04
- GPIO number: GPIO126

```sh
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
gpiochip3: GPIOs 267-309, parent: platform/INT3452:03, INT3452:03:
gpiochip2: GPIOs 310-356, parent: platform/INT3452:02, INT3452:02:
gpiochip1: GPIOs 357-433, parent: platform/INT3452:01, INT3452:01:
gpiochip0: GPIOs 434-511, parent: platform/INT3452:00, INT3452:00:
```

I have searched the information and found that `GPIO_126` should belong to the West Community. But I can't find any pin that corresponds to `GPIO_126`. So, I use the script below to manipulate the pins one by one and use the oscilloscope to look at the voltage.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#set x
pinnum=$1
i=0
direction="out"
cd /sys/class/gpio
until ((i>2))
do
        echo $pinnum > export
        cd gpio$pinnum
        echo $direction > direction
        echo $PWD
        echo "gpio$pinnum print direction"
        cat $PWD/direction
        echo 1 > value
        echo $PWD
        echo "gpio$pinnum print value"
        cat $PWD/value
        cd /sys/class/gpio
        #echo $1 > unexport
        echo "current pinnum $pinnum"
        let pinnum=pinnum+1;
        echo "inc pinnum$pinnum"
        let i=i+1;
        echo "i=$i"
done
```

```sh
$ i2cdetect -l
i2c-3   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
i2c-10  i2c             i915 gmbus misc                         I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
i2c-8   i2c             i915 gmbus dpb                          I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
i2c-11  i2c             DPDDC-A                                 I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
i2c-0   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
i2c-9   i2c             i915 gmbus dpc                          I2C adapter
i2c-7   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
```

I still can't find the pin num of `GPIO_126`. And operating pin339, pin345 pin349 pin350, pin351 ~ pin354, equipment will crash. I also found that GPIO126 is not a normal GPIO, it can also be used as an I2C1_SDA function.
As I understand it, sysfs should be able to control all GPIOs, regardless of function definition. But it seems wrong.

How to turn off I2C function through user layer and use `GPIO_126` as GPIO function?

Comment: First of all, read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579640/2511795 about enumerating GPIOs on Intel platforms. Second, try to avoid using _sysfs_ since it's deprecated interface. What you are looking for is probably this one: `PINCTRL_PIN(2, "LPSS_I2C1_SDA"),` according to https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-broxton.c#L791.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Linux GPIO numbers get their values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532410/how-do-linux-gpio-numbers-get-their-values)