# Problem finding undefined gpio number is raspberry pi 3

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3, embedded-linux, gpio

I am trying to create a driver to access rpi gpio,here is my code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/module.h>


static int hello_init(void)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
        if(!gpio_is_valid(i)){
            printk(KERN_INFO "nope");
        }
        else{
            printk(KERN_INFO "yup");
        }
    }
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello\n");

        return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "bye\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

the problem is with `gpio_is_valid`.It always returns 0 for any value of i. I got it from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/gpio-legacy.txt. Does this not work now, because it's "legacy". if so, what are the workarounds for the same?

Comment: What is your kernel version? -> find the `gpio_is_valid` sources and check it out. Search `bootlin kernel` in google.

Comment: I checked, my uname -r output comes as 5.4.0-1035-raspi, so i searched for the same, there exists to be a function , here is the link https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.103/source/arch/mips/include/asm/mach-au1x00/gpio-au1300.h#L185

Comment: This is for gpio-au1300.h - I do not think this is the chip rpi3 is using. I believe you are using: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.103/source/include/asm-generic/gpio.h#L29 . You should find the `CONFIG_ARCH_NR_GPIO` in kernel config.

Comment: @KamilCuk, oh ok, much thanks, so basically this line (return number >= 0 && number < ARCH_NR_GPIOS; ) is what is getting me 0 always as ARCH_NR_GPIOS=512, but that would mean that any number from 0-511 can be used as a gpio?

Comment: `always as ARCH_NR_GPIOS=512` There's `#ifndef` above. See `CONFIG_ARCH_NR_GPIO` in your kernel config, if set.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it is irrelevant here (I strongly believe it’s 512 **by default**, I.o.w. there’s no other definition provided). You may check how modern GPIO subsystem works, I.e. it uses global number space **internally**, and externally it **must not** be used. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532410/how-do-linux-gpio-numbers-get-their-values/55579640#55579640

Comment: You need to use GPIO descriptors, but they are not available for looping outside the GPIO subsystem, so your code is simply incompatible with the current design, because it’s not clear what its purpose and where are you going to use it. I.o.w. `gpio_*()` **must not** be used in a new code.

Comment: Take a look at this python3 driver -> `pip3 install RPi.GPIO` - you may install pip3 via apt -> `apt install python3-pip`

Comment: @paladin, it’s a custom ugly library, I highly recommend not to use it and switch directly to `libgpiod` (yes, it has Python bindings). Besides the fact that this question is about kernel programming.

Comment: @0andriy I know it's ugly, I meant he may take a look at this approach to get an idea for his own driver. ;-) Because it's hard to find a good specification for the GPIO of the Raspi. This is the official documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/gpio/README.md