# control gpio from linux userspace with linux/gpio.h

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, gpio, libgpiod

I want to write to GPIO 128. Inside `linux/gpio.h` there is `struct gpiohandle_request` which hold information about a GPIO handle request. I saw this [example](https://blog.lxsang.me/post/id/33):

> Let say we want to configure pin 17 and 27 as OUTPUT and we want to write HIGH (1) on pin 17 and LOW (0) on pin 27.

```
struct gpiohandle_request rq;
rq.lineoffsets[0] = 17;
rq.lineoffsets[1] = 27;
rq.lines = 2;
rq.flags = GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT;
```

Now I am confused about lineoffsets. Documentation specify that:

> - @lineoffsets: an array desired lines, specified by offset index for
>   the  associated GPIO device

What does a line mean? If I want to configure `gpio0` to `gpio127` can I make a loop this way:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    rq.lineoffsets[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: First of all, read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579640/2511795 for understanding offsets. Second, why not using the `libgpiod` and its APIs?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @0andriy. I am aware of the existence of libgpiod. I have already use it for some testing. I think it will be easier if I use libgpiod indeed.

Comment: For my 128 gpio, I wanted to use `int gpiod_chip_get_all_lines(struct gpiod_chip *chip, struct gpiod_line_bulk *bulk);` However I noticed that there is `#define GPIOD_LINE_BULK_MAX_LINES 64`. What will be the behaviour then ? Is there a way to handle 128 gpio in one go ? @0andriy

Comment: No, but you may always discuss this with Kent and Bart in the linux-gpio@ mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let say we want to configure pin 17 and 27 as OUTPUT and we want to
> write HIGH (1) on pin 17 and LOW (0) on pin 27.

Setting that structure does not set any GPIOs levels. When you call `ioctl()` it will only set the mode of the appropriate GPIOs.

BTW this structure is depreciated.

> What does a line mean

It is hardware dependent and you need to consult your implementation.

> If i want to configure gpio0 to gpio127

Check if you have enough GPIOs and if the `lineoffsets` field is large enough. Even if you have enough physical GPIOs the control structure does not have to handle them in "one go". The maximum handles number is defined in `GPIOHANDLES_MAX`.

Comment: To be clear, GPIOHANDLES_MAX (64) applies to a single request.  If you need more than 64 lines then you need to spread the lines over multiple requests.  So you can manage 128 lines at a time - just not with a single request.