# Use raspberry pi 4 GPIO with node js

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

I recently tried to use the GPIO of my Raspberry pi 4 with node js.
I managed to get the program to work on my raspberry, but as soon as I wanted to put it on another raspberry, I was no longer able to make it work.

For this, I use the onoff library.
The program is as follows:

```js
var GPIO = require('onoff').Gpio;

var lightPin = new GPIO(23, 'out');

lightPin.writeSync(1)
```

But as soon as I run it, I get the following error:

```bash
node:internal/fs/utils:353
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, write
    at Object.writeSync (node:fs:939:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2355:26)
    at exportGpio (/home/pi4b/API/node_modules/onoff/onoff.js:18:8)
    at new Gpio (/home/pi4b/API/node_modules/onoff/onoff.js:172:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi4b/API/helper.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1201:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1017:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:122:12) {
  errno: -22,
  syscall: 'write',
  code: 'EINVAL'
}

Node.js v21.0.0
```

Version of node.js -> `21.0.0` (the same for both pi)

Version of npm -> `10.5.0` (the same for both pi)

Version of onoff -> `onoff@6.0.3` (the same for both pi)

Debian version -> `12.5` (against 11.9 for the old pi)

For information, the `node_modules` folder was completely deleted and reinstalled with `npm i`.
I also tried with the library `RPi.GPIO` in python which seemed to work correctly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exactly the same problem. Except that I am just reading GPIO pin state with readSync().
Latest rpi OS, NodeJS v21.

Comment: @Didzis Thank you so much. After flashing a new system with Raspberry Pi OS Legacy, it works again!

Comment: Glad it helped. See my answer for the actual solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Raspberry OS kernel addresses GPIO pins yet by another numbering scheme.

```
~ $ cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
gpiochip0: GPIOs 512-569, parent: platform/fe200000.gpio, pinctrl-bcm2711:
...
 gpio-532 (GPIO20              |sysfs               ) in  lo
 gpio-533 (GPIO21              |sysfs               ) in  lo
 gpio-534 (GPIO22              |sysfs               ) in  lo
 gpio-535 (GPIO23              )
 gpio-536 (GPIO24              )
 gpio-537 (GPIO25              )
 gpio-538 (GPIO26              |sysfs               ) in  lo
...
```

If you want to address the GPIO23 pin, you must use the number after gpio-**[number]**

In your case:

```js
var GPIO = require('onoff').Gpio;
var lightPin = new GPIO(535, 'out');
lightPin.writeSync(1)
```

Comment: The problem is the legacy GPIO library the OP is using. Raspberry OS does the correct thing, but nobody should rely on these numbers. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579640/2511795.